# Code 65 build error on Ionic Framework out of nowhere?

Tags: xcode, ionic3

I have been working on an app using Ionic Framework for a while and I have recently gotten this error after running `sudo ionic cordova build ios`:

```
The following build commands failed:
Ld build/emulator/Aqua\ Hydration.app/Aqua\ Hydration normal x86_64
(1 failure)
Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/andrewrodebaugh/aqua/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,Aqua Hydration.xcworkspace,-scheme,Aqua Hydration,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone X,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/andrewrodebaugh/aqua/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/andrewrodebaugh/aqua/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build ios (exit code 1).
```

[Full Log](https://gist.github.com/CosmicWebServices/4b950b41c6eacc63fb7d19b5fb8f6f35)

Also my `ionic info`:

```
$ ionic info

cli packages: (/Users/andrewrodebaugh/aqua/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.18.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.18.0

global packages:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1 

local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.1
Cordova Platforms  : ios 4.6.0-dev
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.8.0

System:

ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
Node       : v6.11.3
npm        : 2.15.12 
OS         : macOS High Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.1 Build version 9B55 

Environment Variables:

ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

backend : legacy
```

Thanks!

Sorry if this information is too much I just have been stuck on this error for too long so I need help.

Comment: Could you please try by opening the `/platform/ios/youApp.xcodeproj` file with XCode and check the `Signing` section, to see if you have your apple account there? https://gyazo.com/604ec5f4adf9a4716a205202cfe637c9

Comment: @sebaferreras yep I have a signed company account there

Comment: with automatic signing no errors